# Objective-C: How to return response from POST method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking

I have a `POST` method that looks like

```
+ (id) post {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    id response = nil;
    [manager POST:@"https://mapp.com/oauth/register"
       parameters:@{@"email" : @"e", @"memberExternalId" : @"m"}
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              response =  responseObject;
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                // (todo) alert on failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];
    return response;
}
```

I thought to abstract this method so that I could reuse it, so I created `id response`.

But when I assign

```
response =  responseObject;
```

I get compilation error as

```
Variable is declared outside the block and is not assignable
```

[image]
**Question**

How can I preserve the `response` so that I can return it later.

Comment: You have to use the __block specifier when you modify a variable inside a block

Comment: @gabbler Yes, that would be true if this was a synchronous method. But it's not, so the whole idea of returning the value from this function is a non-starter. He should employ completion handler pattern (much like the `POST` method, itself).

Answer (score 4):

You're calling an asynchronous method that uses a completion block pattern, so you should do the same. So

- Change the return type to `void`;
- Add block parameter to your method;
- In the `POST` completion block, call your `completionHandler` if there was one supplied;

Thus:

```
+ (void) postWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    // these lines not needed
    //
    // [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    // manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    [manager POST:@"https://mapp.com/oauth/register"
       parameters:@{@"email" : @"e", @"memberExternalId" : @"m"}
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              if (completionHandler) {
                  completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
              }
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              if (completionHandler) {
                  completionHandler(nil, error);
              }
          }];
}
```

Thus, you'd call it like so:

```
[MyClass postWithCompletionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"failed: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    // use the `responseObject` here
}];

// Note, because the above is asynchronous, don't try to use `responseObject` here.
// You can only use it inside the above `completionHandler` block.
```

---

As an aside, you probably don't want to instantiate a new `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for every request. So I'd personally (a) make the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` a property of this class; (b) move the instantiation of the operation manager into some initialization method for the class; and (c) make this "perform request" method an instance method, not a class method. It's not so critical here, but as you contemplate future functionality where you're issuing many requests, it's inefficient to be instantiating new request operation managers all over the place.

Comment: How to model `synchronistic` behavior if `call B` depends on `call A` and so on? is `completionHandler`? is the preferred way? I am confused because code becomes really nested and hard to understand

Comment: Yes, this is the preferred way. If you find your code becoming unwieldy because of all of this nesting, then engage in functional decomposition, moving the nested code into its own method which you'll call from the completion block. While you could consider other techniques to make this inherently asynchronous process behave in a synchronous manner (e.g. semaphores) or establish dependencies between different tasks/operations (e.g. dispatch group notifications or operation queue dependencies), IMHO, these approaches are ill advised.